# Simplify multiple if statements that use if (string.contains())

Tags: c#, if-statement, simplify

I am working on a personal assistant program and I have a method called input_parse() which looks at the input string and checks for words that correspond to "commands" the pseudo code looks like this.

```
if (input.contains("argA")
   {//execute command A}
if (input.contains("argB") && input.contains("argC"))
   {//execute command B}
```

is there a simpler way to tackle this problem perhaps with a string array of commands and then use a switch statement for the commands based on the index of the argument?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for [codereview.se].

Comment: no, there's not a simpler way.  Sure, you can come up with a way that will use significantly less code, but it won't actually be more simple

Comment: What is *command* in your case? Is it some method, some class, or just set of operations?

Comment: Agreed with @SamIam. You could probably use some fancy regex and captures to pull all the args out first, but you'd still have to loop through and use if's or a switch.

Comment: @Sergey The commands include methods generally, which do things like check weather, respond with speech synthesis, check wolfram alpha etc.

Comment: @SamIam So there is no more efficient way of doing this? Would it benefit me to separate the parse method off into a "parser" class with a method called "parse" to clean up the code of the main window?

Comment: @user3538260 I didn't say that there's not a more efficient way.  I said that there is not a more simple way.  "efficient" and "simple" are not interchangeable words

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **Dictionary** where the value will be your command and the key can be your string (arg name).

```
var myCommands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
myCommands.Add("argA", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("arga was passed")));
myCommands.Add("argB", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("argb was passed")));
```

Than you can invoke your commands iterating through the keys of the dictionary. So if both argA and argB are passed both commands will be invoked.

```
foreach (var key in myCommands.Keys)
{
  if (input.Contains(key))
  {
    myCommands[key]();
  }
}
```

This is the easiest way, you don't need to create any class structure or anything like that. Perfect for simple console app.

**EDIT**

To cross match the parameters you can have the following **Dictionary** defined.

```
var myCommands new Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, Action>>();
myCommands.Add(new Func<string, bool>(i => i.Contains("argA")),new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("arga was passed"));
myCommands.Add(new Func<string, bool>(i => i.Contains("argB")),new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("arga was passed"));
myCommands.Add(new Func<string, bool>(i => i.Contains("argB") && e.Contains("argA")),new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("arga & argb was passed"));



foreach (var key in myCommands.Keys)
{
   if (key(input))
   {
      myCommands[key]();
   }
}
```

Comment: The OP's code involves doing something if both B and C are there; this doesn't support that operation.

Comment: Have to agree with @Servy on this one. A dictionary doesn't let me cross reference with multiple arguments like

if (input.contains("what is") && !input.contains("weather"))

I would end up with a conflict.

Comment: You can have Func<bool, string> as a key to match arguments and that will allow. It all depends on your preference and the size of the app. if it something large and enterprise I would go with what @Sergey posted. But if it is a small console app and you want to keep it simple I would just use Action, Func delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You have commands and input arguments which are related to each other. It seems logical to me to encapsulate these two things into one object and keep them close. You can create interface for such objects

```
public interface ICommand
{
    bool CanGetArgumentsFrom(string input);
    void Execute();
}
```

And commands which implement it

```
public class CommandA : ICommand
{
    public bool CanGetArgumentsFrom(string input)
    {
        return input.Contains("argA");
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        /* execute command A */
    }
}
```

And second command

```
public class CommandB : ICommand
{
    public bool CanGetArgumentsFrom(string input)
    {
        return input.Contains("argB") && input.Contains("argC");
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        /* execute command B */
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty readable

```
ICommand[] commands = { new CommandA(), new CommandB() };

foreach(var command in commands)
   if (command.CanGetArgumentsFrom(input))
       command.Execute();
```

---

You even can have method

```
public bool TryExecuteCommand(string input)
{
    if (!CanGetArgumentsFrom(input))
        return false;

    Execute();
    return true;
}
```

Then execution will be even more simple and readable:

```
foreach(var command in commands)
    command.TryExecute(input);
```

---

If you don't want to create named commands, then you can use object which verifies input and executes some action if all required arguments are in place

```
public class Command
{
    string[] arguments;
    Action action;

    public Command(Action action, params string[] arguments)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }

    public bool TryExecute(string input)
    {
        if (!arguments.All(input.Contains))
            return false;

        action();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now with this single class you can create commands:

```
var commands = new Command[] {
    new Command(_ => /* execute A */, "argA"),
    new Command(_ => /* execute B */, "argB", "argC"),
};
```

Comment: @Servy sure, creating objects requires more work, but it will have benefits in maintainability and readability when number of commands and conditions will grow. If there is only two commands, then I would go with OP solution

Comment: I see no improvements in maintainability or readability here.  I can just *glance* at the OP's code and see exactly what it's doing.  it takes me quite a lot longer to parse through your solution, see what it's doing, verify that everything is correct. And of course I'll be looking through a whole mess of different files, rather than having everything right in one screen.  This would be entirely worthwhile if the commands were created from entirely different places, doing radically different things, owned by different types, has no related conditional check, etc., but that's just not the case.

Comment: So far there are a total of 13 possible commands but this is growing and could be expanded to several commands. Would the object option benefit me more in the long run? Also does this method result in multiple class files such as (commandA.cs, commandB.cs etc) or are these additional command classes nested within a single "commands" class file?

Comment: @user3538260 I would go with multiple commands which will be in separate files. You can create *Commands* folder in solution in keep all commands there. Give readable names for commands. E.g. CheckWeatherCommand. You can even replace manual creation of commands by using reflection - get all types which implement `ICommand` from current assembly and instantiate them. Or use configuration for that

Comment: @user3538260 Well, a 13 line `if` statement is still not that long.  It'll still easily fit within a screen.  At that point you'd obviously want to be sure that the body of each block is only one or two lines of code; call out to another method/type if there is more to do, so that the `if` block can stay on one screen.

Comment: @Servy I would suggest you to buy larger 4K screen - it can keep even more lines visible

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I said that those 13 lines would be visible.  I didn't say that's *all* that would be visible.  And I'm not going to fit all 13 different files onto my screen at once no matter how big my monitor is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IEnumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for "or" conditions") or  [`IEnumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for "and" conditions):

```
if (input.contains("argA"))
   {//execute command A}
if (new[] { "argB", "argC" }.All(input.Contains))
   {//execute command B}
```